# Frustration with VBA copy-paste from workbook to workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I've been trying to figure out this subroutine for days. I have read every post about VBA copy-paste on this site and haven't found the answer yet. The concept is so simple but when I run it from a command button, it stops after the copy workbook opens, the copy doesn't execute.  When I step through in debug, it works as expected. Does anyone see any obvious errors?

```
'Must have reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" checked
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject 
Dim wsData as Worksheet
Dim stPDFName As String
Dim stFileName As String
Dim stReport As String
Dim WSCopy As Worksheet
Dim FD As Office.FileDialog
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        FD.InitialFileName = "J:\Laboratory\Reports\2015" 
        FD.Show
        stReport = FD.SelectedItems(1)
        stFileName = fso.GetFileName(stReport)
        stPDFName = Left$(stReport, InStrRev(stReport, ".") - 1) & ".pdf"
    If Dir(stPDFName) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Matching PDF version of this report does not exist":
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Workbooks.Open (stReport)
        For Each WSCopy In Workbooks(stFileName).Worksheets
        If StrComp(WSCopy.CodeName, "Sheet1", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            WSCopy.Range("A1", "BZ5000").Copy
            wsData.Range("E2").PasteSpecial
            wsData.Columns.AutoFit
            Workbooks(stFileName).Close
            Exit For

        End If
    Next WSCopy
    End If
```

Edit: I believe that I have narrowed down the problem to the line:
     `If StrComp(WSCopy.CodeName, "Sheet1", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then`
When I step through the routine, the `StrComp` evaluates properly. If I comment out the `If/End If` lines, the routine works as expected. I use this line to avoid problems that occur when someone moves or renames a worksheet.

Comment: Does it still get as far as bringing up the dialog? If it's running too fast and skipping something then you may need to add a `Do Events` line to slow it down enough to finish one operation before starting the next.

Comment: What about using `WSCopy.Range("A1:BZ5000")` ?

Comment: @JoeMalpass, it makes sense that something might be getting skipped. That would explain why it would work when stepping through but not from a command button. I do get to the filedialog and the chosen workbook opens but nothing gets copied.  Where should I add the "Do Events"? Post an answer with your suggestion so I can select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If my suspicion is correct and the macro is getting ahead of itself, this should slow it down enough to execute properly. My best guess is that is is not allowing time for the value in `stReport` to be set, so I have put a loop there, but you may need to try moving it around. You can test to see where the macro runs away from itself by setting a bunch of breakpoints and seeing which ones allow you to successfully resume the rest of the script after stopping at, and which ones leave it broken.

I'm fairly new to `DoEvents` myself and I'm aware it can be CPU intensive if not used properly, so save your work before testing this just in case you need to force close.

```
'Must have reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" checked
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject 
Dim wsData as Worksheet
Dim stPDFName As String
Dim stFileName As String
Dim stReport As String
Dim WSCopy As Worksheet
Dim FD As Office.FileDialog
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    FD.InitialFileName = "J:\Laboratory\Reports\2015" 
    FD.Show

        Do Until Not(IsEmpty(stReport))
            stReport = FD.SelectedItems(1)
            DoEvents
        Loop

    stFileName = fso.GetFileName(stReport)
    stPDFName = Left$(stReport, InStrRev(stReport, ".") - 1) & ".pdf"
If Dir(stPDFName) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Matching PDF version of this report does not exist":
    Exit Sub
Else
    Workbooks.Open (stReport)
    For Each WSCopy In Workbooks(stFileName).Worksheets
    If StrComp(WSCopy.CodeName, "Sheet1", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        WSCopy.Range("A1", "BZ5000").Copy
        wsData.Range("E2").PasteSpecial
        wsData.Columns.AutoFit
        Workbooks(stFileName).Close
        Exit For

    End If
Next WSCopy
End If
```

Comment: I've tried moving the `DoEvents` loop to different places and it still does the same thing. It opens the file to be copied and then just exits the subroutine. I think that I have isolated the problem to the line `If StrComp(WSCopy.CodeName, "Sheet1", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then`. If I comment that line (and the "end if"), everything works fine.